# При запуске junit не видит класс RASWsLoggerFactory

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Пробую писать `JUnit`. Написал вот такой тест:

```
@Test
public void getEJBDataCS() {
    Object obj = ConfigApplication.getRemouteObject("localhost", "2809", "jndi-имя");
}
```

сам метод `getRemouteObject`:

```
Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        InitialContext jndiCtx;
        if (host != null && port != null) {
            jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, WsnInitialContextFactory.class.getName());
            jndiProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://" + host + ":" + port);
            jndiCtx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
return jndiCtx.lookup(jndiName);
```

Выдаётся ошибка

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.RASWsLoggerFactory

Использую `gradle 2.3`, `websphere 7.0`. В скрипте gradle-сборки есть строчка

```
    compile 'com.ibm:com.ibm.ws.runtime:7.0'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.

Comment: Можно больше информации по логу ошибки пожалуйста